# Convert Radians to Degrees to obtain the refractive index through prism

Tags: c++

I've just now started with the very basics of C++ where I want to develop a program where the user inputs minimum angle of deviation and the program gives the refractive index through an equilateral prism.

But, I'm having a hard time to converting Radians to Degrees in the correct way and hence I'm always getting wrong answers. I'm trying to brainstorm since 5-6 hours, but I'm not getting it.

Here's the code (I'm using Turbo C):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int dm;
    const float pi = 3.142;
    float nu, d;
    repeat: cout<<"Enter the angle of minimum deviation in degrees: ";
    cin>>dm;
    if(dm>=0 && dm<=180)
    {
         d = (pi/180)*dm;
         nu = ((sin((60+d)/2))*2;
         cout<<"The refractive index is "<<nu<<endl;
    } else {
         cout<<"Please enter an angle between 0 to 180 deg"<<endl;
         goto repeat;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

So, for calculating the refractive index through a prism, the formula is `Sin((A+dm)/2) ÷ Sin(A/2)`, where `A` is the angle of prism (which will be 60 deg as it is an equilateral prism) and `dm` is the angle of deviation the user has entered.

But, I always get some crazy answers. I've altered the codes more than a 100 times, but I'm still not getting the correct answer.

So, as to simplify, the formula would become `Sin(30+(dm/2)) * 2`, since the angle of prism will be 60 deg.

What mistakes am I making?

Comment: Use `.` for `double` literals: `180.0`.

Comment: I didn't got you... I'm getting wrong answers, something very different from the expected answer.. So, would you please mind helping me out?

Comment: Start out to correct your calculations as I have advised, go ahead then.

Comment: But, I'm unable to understand what exactly do you mean

Comment: Write `180.0` instead of `180`, `60.0` instead of `60`, a..s.o.

Comment: All trigonometric functions in C and C++ use radians. You need to convert it from degrees to radians, not the opposite direction, as your title suggests. `sin(((60+d)/2)  * pi/180)` - And please use `float` or `double` for your variable `dm`, or do you want to restrict your user to input only whole degrees?

Comment: Also, use the constant `M_PI` instead of writing your own one. If you want to spell it `pi`, use `const float pi = M_PI`.

Comment: OK, I got your point @leemes. No, I don't want to restrict it to whole degrees..

Comment: I see that you convert the input `dm` from degrees to radians and store the result in `d`. This is OK, however your formula uses degrees... You should stick to one system for the formula, and convert everything to/from it when it doesn't fit. For example, stick to degrees and convert the final result to radians before passing it to `sin`. But then remove the conversion of the user input!

Comment: @leemes That's the thing I'm facing difficulty with.. It's all confusing me.. The compiler takes angle in radians, right? Then, the trigo functions of C++ needs angle in radians or degrees? I want to output the refractive index, for which the formula is in degrees? So, can you please alter my above code and help me?

Comment: @ParasShah No, it's your job to fix the code. StackOverflow isn't a code writing factory. You have already all information at hand to do it.

Comment: LOL.. OK.. I'll try it again, the 101st time..

Comment: @ParasShah Next time before you ask: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, @SergeBallesta beat me to it, but I'd like to expand a little bit on his answer. If you get confused by conversions from degrees to radians and vice versa, then you might want to create some explicit variables and conversion functions (thanks to @πάνταῥεῖ for his advice), as I did below. The code can now also take float values as input, as you requested in the comments.

As said before, all trigonometric functions in C take radians. If you want to input and output degrees, then you have to convert the input to radians, next do the calculations, and then convert the result back to degrees before finally printing it out.

If you explicitly want to use `float` values then you should append an `f` to constant values. If you just write `60.0` then it is taken as `double`. However, `M_PI` is taken as `double` anyway.

You also should avoid using `goto`, as using it is not a good style of coding.

Also, you should reset `cin` in the `else` branch. Otherwise your program enters an infinite loop if the user enters characters instead of numbers.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<math.h>

// Fallback, in case M_PI doesn't exist.
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

// Conversion functions to make the code below more readable.
double DEG2RAD(double DEG) {
    return DEG * M_PI / 180.0;
}

double RAD2DEG(double RAD) {
    return RAD * 180.0 / M_PI;
}

int main()
{
    float d_deg, d_rad, nu_rad, nu_deg;
    float prism_angle_rad = DEG2RAD(60.0f);

    while(true) {
        cout << "Enter the angle of minimum deviation in degrees: ";
        cin >> d_deg;
        if(d_deg >= 0.0f && d_deg <= 180.0f) {
            d_rad = DEG2RAD(d_deg);
            nu_rad = sin((prism_angle_rad + d_rad) / 2.0f) / sin(prism_angle_rad / 2.0f);
            nu_deg = RAD2DEG(nu_rad);
            cout << "The refractive index in degrees is: " << nu_deg << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "Please enter an angle between 0.0 to 180.0 degrees." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I do this anyway without the while loop? Just a thought.. Thanks for describing the code. It helped me understand how conversions work in C++. A big thanks :)

Comment: A question.. As I am very new to this.., I did not understand the meaning of the double DEG and Double RAD inside the parantheses and it's direct usage in nu_deg.. Can you please explain it?

Comment: As long as you want to ask the user again until the user enters correct input, a loop is the correct construct to do that. Otherwise you can only use `goto`, but you shouldn't.

Comment: A function can take parameters. If you declare a function, then a parameter consists of a type and a name. The type tells you what kind of variable you can pass to the function and the name is there to use the variable in the function body.

Answer (score 0):

Your *mathematical* formule is Sin((A+dm)/2) ÷ Sin(A/2) with A = 60 degrees or  π/3 radians. Ok sin(A/2) = 1/2 , fine for this part.

But the function `sin` expects an angle in radians. The correct value is:
`((60 + dm) / 2)` in degrees or `(((pi/3) + d) /2)` in radians. With 60 + d you are adding degrees and radians giving... plain wrong results...

Your goto usage is not really justified here, and as said in comments the sin functions expects and returns double not floats. So you should use the full precision that way:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int dm;
    const double pi = M_PI;
    const double pi3 = pi / 3;
    double nu, d;
    for(;;) {
        cout<<"Enter the angle of minimum deviation in degrees: ";
        cin>>dm;
        if(dm>=0 && dm<=180)
        {
             d = (pi/180)*dm;
             nu = (sin((pi3+d)/2))*2; /* ok everything is radian */
             cout<<"The refractive index is "<<nu<<endl;
             break; /* exit from infinite loop */
        } else {
             cout<<"Please enter an angle between 0 to 180 deg"<<endl;
        }
    }
    getch(); /* avoid that ! It is easier when running from IDE but it is ugly 
                Better use a breakpoint on next line. */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sergeballesta for helping out :) Thanks for the in-depth explanation :D As I can select only one answer, I'd chose the above one as it is expanded.. But, your code helped me understand things as well. :)

Comment: That getch() is taught by our college professors to write it in every function at the end.. So, will it have an impact when I'm just beginning with these small programs?

Comment: @ParasShah: If your professors tell you to use it, do use it, at least for your homework :-) . I do not like it because if forces you to include `conio.h` which does not exist outside Microsoft's world, and it should never exist in a professional program.